# How do I mark the generic "T Value" as ready for disposal?

Tags: c#, generics, garbage-collection, dispose, idisposable

I've created a class `BinaryTree<T>`.  I wrote the following to dispose it:

```
public override void Dispose()
{
    this.Key = null;
    //delete this.Value;
    if(this.LeftLeaf != null) this.LeftLeaf.Dispose();
    this.LeftLeaf = null;
    if(this.RightLeaf != null) this.RightLeaf.Dispose();
    this.RightLeaf = null;
    base.Dispose();
}
```

My question is how do I mark the "T Value" as ready for disposal? I can't set it to null because you can't set generics to null. T could be a giangantic class, but it may not be using `IDisposable` so you can't call `Dispose` on it. Since this is "safe" class written like an "unsafe" class I don't trust GC to figure out it's not being used anymore.

Comment: You can set generics to null if you declare them as `where T : class` - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx

Comment: How come you don't trust the GC?

Comment: Why do you need to mark it as "ready for disposal"? Things are ready for Disposal when you call Dispose. I assume you mean garbage collection, to which I would say: "Don't worry about it. The GC will take care of it."

Comment: You can also write `this.Value = default(T)` which will set to null for reference types.

Comment: You appear to be confusing `Dispose`, garbage collection, and possible several other things. Read though some of the high voted `idisposable` questions.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is concretely meant by *this is "safe" class written like an "unsafe" class*, please?

Comment: I've been writing C# code for around 10 years. I've worked on systems where you deal with very large datasets and caches. Once you get in the over 3 GB realm of cached objects, or datasets, you'll find GC is not what it claims to be in theory. You'll find you do in fact have to set objects to null so that GC finally understands you do not wish to use that object anymore. Yes I know about AppFabric, etc. That's a discussion for you to have with my CTO later. One has to live in the constraints one is given.

Comment: A safe class is one in which you don't do any memory referecing, you let C# handle that.  An unsafe class is one in which you handle the memory yourself.  A BinaryTree is a classic "memory referencing" solution to a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If for some reason you're writing a generic collection in which you know that the elements of your collection will implement `IDisposable` **and the collection will be responsible for disposing of them** (which, generally is something you would not expect of the collection) then you should be adding the generic constraint `where T : IDisposable` so that you can dispose of all of the items.

When it comes to normal collection of managed types, as opposed to unmanaged resources, you don't need to do anything.  There's no need to set the fields to null, or the value to null.  If the entire collection isn't referenced anywhere then the GC will collect it, and any values not referenced anywhere, even without you nulling out all fields.

> I don't trust GC to figure out it's not being used anymore

That's going to make C# pretty much unusable for you as a language.  By design, not only do you not have to manually release managed resources, you *can't* even if you wanted to.  There is no way for you to *force* a managed object to be cleaned up immediately.  You can only manually clean up *unmanaged* resources.  If, for some reason, this is unacceptable for your application and you must have complete control over the memory management of your program you'll want to use some other language with more explicit memory management (or perhaps write some particularly sensitive parts in another language, and interop with C# for the rest).

Comment: Maybe the remark about the generic constraint should be extended with a remark how values of type `T` can be tentatively cast to `IDisposable` with the `as` operator and then disposed of if appropriate. Enforcing `IDisposable` for every element in the collection might not be desirable in some situations.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper While that's *possible*, it's almost certainly not *desirable*.  As I said, it generally shouldn't be the case that a collection is responsible for disposing of the generic objects given to it.  Some other types of generic code, besides collections, occasionally are used to take "ownership" of a disposable object, in which case the type would *need* to implement `IDisposable` for you to use it as a generic argument.

Comment: I was rather thinking along the lines of generic code that takes "ownership" of an object that may or may not be disposable. Happens, for example, when the object might be something linked to unmanaged things such as a network connection, or alternatively something that just outputs some hard-coded stuff that doesn't need any disposing.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper And my advice is to avoid such situations at all costs, as it's a highly confusing situation to be in for users of your type.  My impression of the OP's situation, given that he's writing a custom binary tree class, is that he's *not* in that situation, so I wouldn't consider suggesting it helpful.

Comment: I've been writing C# code for around 10 years. I've worked on systems where you deal with very large datasets and caches.  Once you get in the over 3 GB realm of cached objects, or datasets, you'll find GC is not what it claims to be in theory.  You'll find you do in fact have to set objects to null so that GC finally understands you do not wish to use that object anymore.  

Yes I know about AppFabric, etc.  That's a discussion for you to have with my CTO later. One has to live in the constraints one is given.

Comment: @Lup Yes, if you have something like a cache it's important to actually remove the reference to objects once they "expire" to allow them to be collected by the GC; by the same logic, if you remove an item from a collection you shouldn't hold onto a reference and just have it marked as "dead", because that prevents GC.  However, you seem to be describing a situation whereby the entire collection is known by the GC to be dead, the objects aren't referenced anywhere else, but the items in it still aren't collected.  That just won't happen.

Comment: I know you think that.  And I know M$ claims that. But once you actually start coding and using and analyzing very large data structures you will find that simply does not happen. You have to "convince" GC that you are in fact not using that object anymore by any means you have. That includes forcing GC to happen in some cases.

Comment: @Lup It sounds like you're talking about a program allocating/deallocating memory so fast the GC's just aren't happening enough, in which case the problem is not solved by setting fields to null.  The issue is not with the GC marking an object as "alive" when it's not, but rather how often/when it chooses to run a collection.  As I've said, in some programs with a memory model, or requirements relating to memory, beyond what the GC supports, you may need to use another language.  Such situations are very rare though.

Answer (score 3):

This will work for all T's (classes or structs):

```
public void DisposeIfApplicable(ref T value)
{
    if(value is IDisposable)
    {
        ((IDisposable)value).Dispose();
    }
}
```

or just inline it as

```
if(this.LeftLeaf is IDisposable)
{
    ((IDisposable)this.LeftLeaf).Dispose();
}

if(this.RightLeaf is IDisposable)
{
    ((IDisposable)this.RightLeaf).Dispose();
}
```

Edit:
I didn't have the ref for the DisposeIfApplicable function, thus any structs will stay un-disposed (the passed copy would get disposed, though).

Answer (score 1):

Most generic abstract data type implementations (e.g. List, Dictionary) don't implement `IDisposable` nor do they dispose of the contained objects, since that's "outside of the scope" of what that type should be doing. As such, in your class I would simply do:

```
this.LeftLeaf = default(T);
```

To remove the references, or:

```
this.LeftLeaf = null;
```

If you specify in the generic constraints that `where T : class`

It really should be the higher level consumer of your BinaryTree class that would worry about disposing of anything contained in this tree.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to set a `T` value to `null`, you can specify a `class` constraint on your `T` generic. That will force your tree to only accept classes for your `T` generic parameter. You can also use `as IDisposable` with null checks to see if you can call `.Dispose()`:

```
public class MyBinaryTree<T>
    where T : class
{
    /* ... class code here ... */

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        this.Key = null;

        //delete this.Value;
        var leftLeafDisposable = this.LeftLeaf as IDisposable;
        if(leftLeafDisposable != null) leftLeafDisposable.Dispose();            
        this.LeftLeaf = null;

        var rightLeafDisposable = this.LeftLeaf as IDisposable;
        if(rightLeafDisposable != null) rightLeafDisposable.Dispose();
        this.RightLeaf = null;

        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you slightly misunderstood.  //delete this.Value is meant to delete the "T Value" parameter.  The leafs are already known to be disposable cause they are BinaryTree objects I created.

Answer (score 0):

There are very few times code should check if something implements `IDisposable` and dispose it if so; in nearly every case, the requirement stems from a factory method whose return type *should have implemented `IDisposable` but didn't* (e.g. `IEnumerator.GetEnumerator`).  Unless one is calling such a factory, one should not call `Dispose` on objects one receives but is not particularly expecting to hold resources, *even the actual object instances happen to implement `IDisposable`*.

The compiler-generated types for C# iterators, for example, will implement `IDisposable`; calling `Dispose` on an iterator during the lifetime of the first enumerator it returns from a `GetEnumerator` call will invalidate that enumerator and force any `finally` blocks within it to run.  The call won't invalidate the iterator, nor will it affect any enumerators other than the first.  The fact that the type of iterator instances implements `IDisposable` is an implementation detail rather than part of their contract, and client code should ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Rereading your question, I think I may have misunderstood it previously.  If something which holds a `T` (e.g. an array of type `T[]`) is needed, but a particular `T` within it is not, you should set that particular `T` to `default(T)`.